# Recently started mediation,on my own,had a weird sensation

Tags: meditation

I recently tried meditating.I only did it for about 5 minutes. But had a sense of vibration on the center of my forehead. So is it good or bad? What should i do?

Comment: Read [this](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/8894/9846) , you will find another link in this answer that will provide an [pdf file](http://htm.sirimangalo.org/) of 52 pages, its a beginner guide to meditation.

Answer (score 1):

All kinds of weird experiences arise in meditation. If you react with craving or aversion then you are regressing in your meditation. Be progressive by giving it not importance and experiencing the vibrating sensation and the impermanent or arsing and passing nature of the experience.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are concentrating too hard; with too much force.

Proper meditation 'lets go' rather than tries to attain.

Make the mind quiet, gentle & still rather than 'push' with force & ambition.

Always remember the Buddha taught his path is the abandoning/giving up of craving.